# Change document library document file entry type programmatically

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to change document types (FileEntryType) for a large list of files in Liferay Document Library, but I have not been able to do so.

After hours of googeling, testing and familiarizing myself with Liferay Github repo, I decided to come here and ask for help.

This is what I have used:

```java
ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();

List<DLFileEntry> filesToBeUpdated = DLFileEntryServiceUtil.getFileEntries(
                                                groupId, 0, fileEntryTypeId,
                                                0, 10000, OrderByComparator);

for (DLFileEntry file : filesToBeUpdated) {
    System.out.println("Changing file: "+ file.getName());

    serviceContext.setAttribute("fileEntryTypeId", fileEntryTypeId);

    DLAppServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(file.getFileEntryId(), file.getName(),
                        file.getMimeType(), null, file.getDescription(),
                        null, false, null, file.getSize(), serviceContext);
}
```

The files I used for testing are found correctly. The problem is with updating in the for loop: It throws always PortletException. How can I change the FileEntryType correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also accomplish this with DLAppServiceUtil by setting the field in the ServiceContext that you pass in as the last parameter:

sc.setAttribute("fileEntryTypeId", liferayDocumentType);

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use DLAppServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(...)? DLFileEntryServiceUtil [has updateFileEntry method](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLFileEntryServiceUtil.html#updateFileEntry%28long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20long,%20java.util.Map,%20java.io.File,%20java.io.InputStream,%20long,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext%29) that accepts long fileEntryTypeId as a parameter.